# Solve for $z$ in equation $|z-a|+|z+a|=2|c|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve for $z$ in the equation $$|z-a|+|z+a|=2|c|.$$ My idea is to square both sides

$$|z-a|^2+|z+a|^2+2|(z-a)(z+a)|=4|c|^2$$

Using $|z|^2=z\bar{z}$, this becomes

$$|z|^2+|a|^2+|(z-a)(z+a)|=2|c|^2$$

I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve for $z$"? The set of solutions is an ellipse, after all :)

Comment: As long as $\lvert c\rvert > \lvert a\rvert$ ;)

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, I thought maybe there's some way to simplify this further. But yes, now I realize it's an ellipse, so it's already in the best form. :)

Comment: @DanielFischer You mean $|c|>|a|$?

Comment: @MikaH. Yes, certainly, thanks for noticing.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You got me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write down all solutions in   parametric form. If $|a|=|c|$, they are $z=ta$, $-1\le t\le 1$. If $|a|<|c|$, we have an ellipse with focal distance $2|a|$ and major axis $2|c|$. The minor semiaxis is $\sqrt{|c|^2-|a|^2}$. Hence, the parametric equation is 
$$
z = \frac{|c|}{|a|} a \cos t + \frac{\sqrt{|c|^2-|a|^2}}{|a|} ia\sin t,\quad 0\le t\le 2\pi
$$
This works when $|c|=|a|$, too.